# How to toggleClass do display div on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mobile menu that does not open on mobile devices. 
The link that can only be seen on mobile devices when clicked does not open the mobile menu.

When i click on the below link the class in the main menu should become main-menu show however nothing happens. I am not sure why it is not working

Html:

```
  <a class="cmn-toggle-switch cmn-toggle-switch__htx open_close" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Menu mobile</span></a>
  <div id="header_menu">
    <div class="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="submenu">
```

JS

```
$('a.open_close').on("click",function() {
    $('.main-menu').toggleClass('show');
    $('.layer').toggleClass('layer-is-visible');
});
$('a.show-submenu').on("click",function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("show_normal");
});
$('a.show-submenu-mega').on("click",function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("show_mega");
});
if($(window).width() <= 480){
    $('a.open_close').on("click",function() {
    $('.cmn-toggle-switch').removeClass('active')
});
}
```

I think the mistake is in the JS but i am not sure . For more info the link to the site is http://www.wanderintown.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the .on() function before the HTML has finished loaded. so the button dosen't exsist at the moment.

Try put it inside:

```
$(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
  $('a.open_close').on("click",function() {
    $('.main-menu').toggleClass('show');
    $('.layer').toggleClass('layer-is-visible');
  });
});
```